# react native try catch navigation errors

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have some nested navigation that (simplified) looks something like

```
Main Stack

   Screen A

   Screen B

   Screen C

   Screen D -> Tab Navigator

                  Screen E

                  Screen F -> Stack Navigator

                                 Screen G
```

I'm trying to create a generic function that will navigate from Screen A to Screen B or C or G.

When I'm navigating I'd like to use navigation.replace, but this doesn't work with Screen G as it is not part of the Main Stack. So I was trying to something like

```
try{
   navigation.replace(ScreenX, params)
}
catch (error) {
   navigation.navigate(ScreenX, params)
}
```

but it doesn't actually catch the error and I get a red screen.

Is it possible to use try catch when navigating in react native?

Answer (score -1):

It depends on your requirements, you must add `componentDidCatch` for every navigation dear component.